# Why is the value of r in $r=\cos θ$ never negative?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

The graph of $r=\cos θ$ forms a circle with radius $.5$ and around $(1,0)$. However, in terms of Cartesian plane coordinates, why doesn't the $r$ value go into the second and third quadrants? Wouldn't $r$ be negative when $θ$ is in the second and third quadrants?

Comment: $r$ *is* negative, and therefore the polar equation plots "backward" through the origin. As $\theta$ move through the Quadrant 2 and 3, the circle is traced in Quadrant 4 and 1. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127240/409) features a different curve, but may help in visualizing this.

Comment: Take into account that the answer in the link above in wrong. The first graph in there is actually that of $r^2=\sin^2(3\theta)$, not of $r=\sin(3\theta)$.

Comment: @fourRightRotations: Nope, it's $r=\sin(3\theta)$. The graph of $r^2=\sin^2(3\theta)$ would have six petals.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct $r$ is negative when $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta < \frac{3\pi}{2}$, but since $r$ is negative, it points in the opposite direction of the $\theta$. Thus, the point $(r,\theta)=(-1,\pi)$ does not map to $(x,y)=(-1,0)$, but to $(x,y) = (1,0)$

Comment: There are no points with $r<0$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: @fourRightRotations: I disagree with that statement.

Comment: @Blue You can disagree all you want. You would still be wrong.

Comment: @fourRightRotations Is it not just a matter of definition? This is not worth arguing about.

Comment: @fourRightRotations: Allowing $r$ to be negative is what allows [polar roses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)) of the form $r = \cos(k\theta)$ to have $2k$ petals when $k$ is even.

Comment: @Blue Certainly not needed. Therefore, it is not what allows it.

Comment: @fourRightRotations: Without negative $r$, how does one plot the "diagonal" petals of $r=\cos(4\theta)$?

Answer (score 1):

$r$ can be negative.

When $\theta$ is in Quadrant II or III, $r=\cos\theta$ is negative and the point is located in the opposite quadrant.

But as $\cos(\pi+\theta)=-\cos\theta$, $(r_0,\cos\theta_0)$ and $(-r_0,\cos(\theta_0+\pi))$ coincide.

Answer (score 0):

I’d like you to first think of the equation $y=x^2$ in the Cartesian coordinate $(x,y)$-plane. That condition is a *restriction* over the plane that famously identifies those points whose $y$ value (height fron $x$ axis) is exactly the square of their $x$ value.

Now move back to polar coordinate $(r, \theta)$-plane. The equation $r = \cos\theta$ identifies those points whose $r$-value (distance from the origin) is exactly $\cos$ of their $\theta$ value (angle from $x$ axis). But *$r$ is always greater than zero* 
(and $\theta$ is always between $\pm\pi$), so the condition is not meaningless unless $\theta$ makes the cosine positive, that is $\theta$ is between $\pm\pi/2$.

You’d just gotten it the other way around.

---

**ADDENDUM.** (Technical) The reason why I require $r>0$ and $-\pi< \theta < \pi$ is because I want polar coordinates to be consistent with the usual definitions of curvilinear coordinates in analysis, or coordinate charts in differential geometry. I want my coordinates to be a homeomorphism between an open subset of the plane (in this case the plane without the negative $x$ axis and the origin) and another open subset of the plane ($(0,+\infty)\times(-\pi,+\pi)$), and in particular a bijection. Otherwise it would be meaningless to even say that the polar coordinates of a point on the plane are such and such, because multiple answers would do. Notice that my approach provides a sensible answer to the OP’s doubts without recurring to weird ideas such as “negative distance from the origin”.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Short summary:

In **polar coordinates** $r$ is the **distance** of a Cartesian point $(x,y)$ from the origin 
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 0$$
And there are no $r<0$ for whatever "going backwards through the origin".

p.s.:

But what you can do is the following:
A curve $r=r(\theta)$ corresponds to the parametric curve
$$(x(\theta),y(\theta))=r(\theta)\cdot(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$$
This form works also for $r(\theta)<0$. So, you can see this as an extension of a polar curve to allow for "negative radii". In this case the corresponding polar curve would be
$$(x(\theta),y(\theta))=|r(\theta)|\cdot(-\cos(\theta),-\sin(\theta))= |r(\theta)|\cdot(\cos(\theta-\pi),\sin(\theta-\pi))=$$ $$=\hat r(\phi)\cdot(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi)) \mbox{ where } \phi = \theta-\pi \mbox{ and } \hat r(\phi) = |r(\theta)|$$