# polar graphing, supposed range is between $0$ to $\pi,$ but graph drawn range from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, circles, polar-coordinates

I'm currently studying "area bound by polar curves" on khan academy, and below is one of the question I have encountered

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am puzzled by part $2$ of the official solution. I can't seem to figure out why the graph is drawn between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2,$ even though the supposed range is between $0$ and $\pi?$

Could someone please provide some additional explanation/clarification?

Comment: For $\pi/2<\theta<\pi$, we have that $\theta \sin(2\theta)$ is negative, so $r$ is plotted "backwards" through the origin, tracing the curve in the fourth quadrant. (See, for instance, [the animations in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127240/409).)